# Enumerating the reals using a definability hierarchy

Tags: set-theory, incompleteness

(edit : for those perplexed with the meaning of "truth" in the following,
let us say we believe in the consistency of ZFC, use the completeness
theorem and reason in a fixed model $M$ of ZFC. The answer to the question
may therefore depend on the choice of $M$).

Let $A_0$ denote the standard alphabet for expressing formulas in
set theory, $A_0=\lbrace \in,\wedge,\vee,\Rightarrow,\neg,\forall,\exists\rbrace
\cup V$ where $V$ is a countable stock of variables. The set $\Phi_0$
of all words over $A_0$ forming meaningful statements is obviously countable,
so  let $b_0: {\mathbb N} \to \Phi_0$ be a computable bijection. Define a 
new predicate $T_1(n)$ which says if statement $b_0(n)$ is true, and let
$A_1=A_0\cup \lbrace T_1\rbrace$. The set $\Phi_1$
of all words over $A_1$ forming meaningful statements is obviously countable,
so  let $b_1: {\mathbb N} \to \Phi_1$ be a computable bijection. Define a 
new predicate $T_2(n)$ which says if statement $b_1(n)$ is true, and let
$A_2=A_1\cup \lbrace T_2\rbrace$.

Using transfinite induction and the axiom of choice, one can iterate this construction and
produce a sequence $(A_{\alpha})_{\alpha < \aleph_1}$ of countable alphabets
such that $A_{\lambda}=\cup_{\alpha < \lambda} A_{\alpha}$ for limit
$\lambda$ and $A_{\alpha+1}=A_{\alpha}\cup \lbrace T_{\alpha+1}\rbrace$
where $T_{\alpha+1}(n)$ says if statement $b_{\alpha}(n)$ is true,
where $b_{\alpha}$ is a bijection ${\mathbb N} \to \Phi_{\alpha}$,
and $\Phi_{\alpha}$ is the set of  all words over $A_\alpha$ forming 
meaningful statements.

Say that a subset $x$ of $\omega$ is $\alpha$-definable if there is a 
one-variable formula $\phi$ over $A_{\alpha}$ such that 
$x=\lbrace y \in \omega \ | \ \phi(y) \rbrace$. Denote by $D_{\alpha}$
the set of all  $\alpha$-definable subsets of $\omega$.

If ${\cal P}(\omega)=\bigcup_{\alpha < \aleph_1} D_{\alpha}$, then
the Continuum Hypothesis holds. Is the converse true ?

Note that it is not clear if the $D_{\alpha}$ sets depends on the $b_{\alpha}$ bijections chosen (it is easy to see that for finite $\alpha$, $D_{\alpha}$ is independent of the choice made). So when I ask if the converse is true, I'm asking whether under CH we have
${\cal P}(\omega)=\bigcup_{\alpha < \aleph_1} D_{\alpha}$ for a suitable choice of the $b_{\alpha}$.

Comment: I'm not quite clear as to what is "true" here. Are you giving a truth definition to the universe? Because there is no such $T_1$. Not even if you allow $b_0$ to be arbitrary.

Comment: You may have to clarify the context because there is no definition of $T_1[x]$ of the truth of a general formula $b_0[x]$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I hope my small edit clarifies my question

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not sure what you mean by "there is no such $T_1$". The whole point of the construction is that by Tarski's undefinability of truth, $T_1$ is not expressible inside $\Phi_0$, so that $\Phi_1$ is strictly more expressive that $\Phi_0$. This yields of sequence of more and more expressive set of formulas

Comment: When you wrote the question, you did not mention definability inside a model or outside a model. You can't quite be confused by a comment on the lacking of your original phrasing.

Comment: I also don't see why you can find computable bijections after $A_{\omega_1^{CK}}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I never claimed that all the $b_{\alpha}$ were "computable". The very
first steps (for finite $\alpha$) are clearly computable, the very 
last steps are clearly "non-computable" (and rely on ineffective
use of the axiom of the choice combined with transfinite induction), with 
an unclear phase between the two extremes.

Comment: Then why is $b_0$ computable? It's confusing when the first choice of function is computable, and the rest are not.